# How to find the density of a normalized random variable?

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function, change-of-variable

> If we are given the probability density function of a multidimensional random variable, how to find the density of the corresponding normalized random variable?

In other words, given $f_{X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n}(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ to be pdf of $(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n)$, how to find the density of $\left(\frac{X_1}{\sqrt{X_1^2+X_2^2+\dots+X_n^2}},\frac{X_2}{\sqrt{X_1^2+X_2^2+\dots+X_n^2}},\dots,\frac{X_n}{\sqrt{X_1^2+X_2^2+\dots+X_n^2}}\right)$?

I was thinking of defining $\frac{X_i}{\sqrt{X_1^2+X_2^2+\dots+X_n^2}}=Y_i$ for all $i$, then writing $(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n) = (rY_1,rY_2,\dots,rY_n)$ and then using Change of variable formula. But that didn't work because the Jacobian matrix becomes rectangular then.

Comment: Normalizing a multivariate rv $X \in \mathbb{R}^d$ with known variance-covariance matrix $\Sigma=Q^TQ$ with $Q$ invertible and mean vector $\mu$ would entail computing $Z:=Q^{-1}(X-\mu)$

Comment: No @Snoop, I am not normalizing in that sense. That will give you multivariate standard normal random variables, and the coordinates can still vary such that $||Z||\ne1$. I am dividing all the coordinates by their Euclidean norm.

Comment: @PaulFrost, Yes I've solved it now. Thank you btw!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're heading to the right direction there. You get rectangular Jacobian because once $n-1$ of the $Y_{i}$ are determined, the last $Y_{i}$ is fixed (because their sum of squares equals one).

I would define $Y_{1}=\sqrt{1-\sum_{i=2}^{n}{Y_{i}^{2}}}$, find the density function of $\left(r,Y_{2},Y_{3},...,Y_{n}\right)$ using Change of Variable and then integrate w.r.t $r$ from $0$ to $\infty$.

Comment: I was also think of that, but then $Y_1=|X_1|$ instead of $X_1$, and I don't want this.